# Why is the formula for standard error of the sample mean and standard error of the sample proportion different?

Tags: variance, sampling, standard-deviation, standard-error

Trying to understand this intuitively and haven't been able to find any explanations for this.

If the formula for the standard error of the sample proportion is:
$$\sigma_\hat p = \frac{\sigma_X}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{n\!\cdot\!p(1-p)}}{n}=\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$$

where $X$ is the sum of the results of $n$ independent trials of picking a $1$ or an $0$,

why is the formula for the standard error of the sample mean,

$$\sigma_\bar x=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

?

In both formulas, the sample size, $n$, is deflating the standard error, but why is one deflating by $n$ and the other one by $\sqrt{n}$ ?

Comment: You are not comparing the same things.  Consider a dataset consisting only of zeros and ones and apply both formulas: you will see they are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

You have various different standard deviations and standard errors there.  Trying to unpick them, for given $p$:

- An individual trial has variance $p(1-p)$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$
- The sum of $n$ independent trials has variance $np(1-p)$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$
- The mean of $n$ independent trials has variance $\frac1n p(1-p)$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\frac1n p(1-p)}$; this last expression is sometimes called the standard error of the sample mean or of the sample proportion

So the standard deviation of the mean is indeed $\frac1n$ of the standard deviation of the sum, and is $\sqrt{\frac1n}$ of the standard deviation of an individual trial, as you say in your question. You are comparing different things, as whuber has commented.